# Difference between initializing using ternary condition vs bracket initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just come across of this variable initialization

```
let { page = 1 } = req.query;
```

where if `req.query.page` doesn't exist, `page = 1`. But if there is `req.query.page` (let say 6), `page = 6`

I just want to ask if there is any difference the above initialization on this

```
let page = req.query.page? req.query.page : 1
```

and at this point I like using the first since it's less in code. Any idea how the first one works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the default destructuring syntax will assign 1 *only* if the property is undefined. In contrast, the conditional operator will assign whenever the property is falsy.

```js
const req = { query: {
  page: 0
}};

let { page = 1 } = req.query;
console.log(page);
```

```js
const req = { query: {
  page: 0
}};

let page = req.query.page? req.query.page : 1
console.log(page);
```

So it's slightly different, but doing `let { page = 1 } = req.query;` should be fine as long as you keep in mind what it means.